# Find total number of $count++ in while loop

Tags: php, while-loop, counter

I have a basic counter going that echoes out the number for each paragraph in my content, and I need to find the total number of loops for my counter...

```
<?php
    $count = 0;
    // check if the repeater field has rows of data
    if( have_rows('each_class_event') ):
    // loop through the rows of data
    while ( have_rows('each_class_event') ) : the_row(); ?>
        <?php $count++; ?>

    <div class="eachOne">
       <div class="classInfo">
            <p>Session <?php echo $count; ?></p>
        </div>
     </div>
```

in the paragraph I need it to be something like:

```
    <p>Session <?php echo $count; ?> of <?php echo $totalCount; ?></p>
```

Comment: So what the problem?

Comment: not possible as written, since `$totalCount` won't be available under AFTER you finish the while_loop().

Comment: Have you tried <?php echo count(have_rows('each_class_event')); ?>

Comment: have_rows returns a boolean value, so that wont do much . all examples i have seen show the need to do a loop for a count, horrible, but you may just have to loop twice (1 for count, 2 for display).

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was treating the custom field in WordPress as an array and using this...

```
    <p>Session <?php echo $count; ?> of <?php echo count( get_field('each_class_event') ); ?></p>
```